# How to avoid a input value from being overwritten when they are being pushed to an array in React.js

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to take a value of one input from a collection of inputs that I had used only one onChange function and useState hook to collect their values.

In my function handleAnswer which is called on click event, I destructured the state to get values for one input. I wanted that value to be pushed to an empty array the problem is that the value keeps overwriting itself instead of being saved on each click, how can I solve this?

```
const mychoices= []
const initialValues ={
    title:'', 
    quiz:'',
    answer:'',
    start:'',
    stop:'',
    duration:'',  
    choice:""
}

const [values,setValue] = useState(initialValues)
const handleInput =(e)=>{
 const name = e.target.name
 const myvalue = e.target.value
 setValue({
    ...values,[name]:myvalue
 })
}

console.log(test)

Add()
const handleAnswer =()=>{
    const {choice}= values
    const newArray=[...mychoices,choice]
    mychoices.push(newArray)
    setValue(initialValues) 
    console.log(mychoices)
}
```

Comment: Your `choices` are not part of any component state but should be

Answer (score 0):

The bug is inside handleAnswer function

**Try this code**

```
const handleAnswer = () => { 
    mychoices.push(values.choice)
    setValue(initialValues) 
    console.log(mychoices)
}
```